# Converting df to nested dictionary based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, nested

I am trying to create a nested dictionary in the form of:

```py
{
    "Principal Venue Product Code": {
        ["Spot month Lim", "Aggregate Lim"]: ["Venue Product Codes"]
    }
}
```

I am using the default dict method to transform a pandas dataframe and have the following code (creating df code not relevant):

```py
ifeu_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for principal in df["Principal Venue Product Code"]:
    if principal not in ifeu_dict.keys():
        ifeu_dict[principal] = []


# adding IFEU limits
for (col, row) in df.iterrows():
    if (
        row.loc["Venue MIC"] == "IFEU"
        and len(ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]]) < 2
    ):
        if type(row.loc["Spot month single limit#"]) == int:
            ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]].append(
                row.loc["Spot month single limit#"]
            )
            ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]].append(
                row.loc["Other month limit#"]
            )
        if type(row.loc["Spot month single limit#"]) == str:
            try:
                int(str(row.loc["Spot month single limit#"])[0])
                ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]].append(
                    int(
                        str(row.loc["Spot month single limit#"])
                        .split()[0]
                        .replace(",", "")
                    )
                )
                ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]].append(
                    int(str(row.loc["Other month limit#"]).split()[0].replace(",", ""))
                )
            except ValueError:
                pass
```

Beyond this, my code stops working. I have added the below to the above loop to try and get it to work:

```py
ifeu_dict[row.loc["Principal Venue Product Code"]][
    row.loc["Spot month single limit#"], row.loc["Other month limit#"]
].append(row.loc["Venue Product Codes"])
```

The first section should make a {principal:[empty list]} variable, whilst the second part should be adding venue product codes to the `{bucket:list limit}` if they have the bucket on the previous column.

Thanks for your time, people.